# Picking the last registration from a database table

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I want to pick up the last registration from a table to use it, can someone help me with that? I have some ideas but I don't know how to code this.

Comment: SELECT MAX(registration) from YourTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite vague. I will try to answer this, it depends on how you are trying to fetch the detail.

From SQL, if you are having a procedure, you can simply use ORDER BY DESC and select the top most registration column; Or can also use the MAX by clause (if the registration column will increment).

If there are multiple registration entries with the same value, you need to use the PARTITION BY clause to sort out the required entry based on your condition.

If you want to do this directly from the code, then you can use LINQ to perform similar operations